# Difference between Unicode, UTF-8 and code pages

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character

Can anyone explain me what is the difference between Unicode, UTF-8 and code pages? Are they related to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Unicode defines a numeric value (codepoint) for every character.

Codepage/charset encodings define the relationship between bytes and Unicode codepoints.  Since files generally consist of bytes, this is a useful thing to nail down.

UTF-8 is a specific byte encoding for Unicode codepoints.  For instance, on Windows it is implemented as codepage 65001.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode is a standard which defines characters, their encoding, and much more (normalization, transformation in lowercase, upper case, numeric values (of numeric characters), collation/sorting, character characteristics, etc.)

So, in Unicode (UnicodeData.txt) you have

```
0041;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;0061;
```

So the letter "`LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A`" has code `U+0041`, it is a upper case letter (`Lu` as *General Category*), it should not be reordered (it is not a combining char), the `0`, it is a *Left_To_Right* (`L`) letter (useful when displaying text), not mirrored if the character is written in in Right_To_Left (`N`), and `U+0061` is the alternate case (which it is the *LATIN SMALL LETTER A*.

Note: there are many more files, and rules. Sometime rules are more complex (e.g. the other case: it may consist in more characters).

So Unicode gives a code (e.g. to *Latin Capital Letter A*, the Unicode standard, very long, it has also long descriptions of alphabets, which may help you to find the "Unicode name"). Display, text processors, fonts engines, and so on, they care just about Unicode (and the meaning of the characters, and the properties of the character).

Unicode defines also encodings. We need a way to represent a codepoint (e.g. `U+0041`). Unicode defines different encodings: UTF-16, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32, UTF32LE, UTF-32BE, UTF-8. Unicode sequences will be translated in a binary text in different ways, according the encoding. UTF-8 is popular, because it is compatible to ASCII (ASCII texts are also UTF-8 text).  Note: UTF-8 is a variable length encoding, so some characters are represented with one byte, and some with 2, 3 or 4 bytes (this is the main disadvantage, so internally, many languages and operating systems use UTF16 or UTF32).

Files and various protocols (e.g. email, html documents) care about how to transmit (on a digital/numeric medium) data, so they must encode character strings (and also decode byte-streams into strings). UTF-8 is just one way to encode Unicode strings, and in any case, you may have also non Unicode encodings, e.g. ASCII, "ANSI", Latin-1, etc.

Note: One principle of Unicode is also to be able to convert most of the other encodings (pre Unicode) to Unicode and back, without losing information. This is a reason of the success of Unicode: it is a strict superset of nearly all other encodings.

Before Unicode we had many other encodings, often just 8bit encodings. 8bit means 256 characters, which are not sufficient to represent any language. So, we had many different encodings, e.g. one per language / group (and often not enough, so with various tricks, or with just a definition of some characters in a higher level protocol, e.g. many of the typography symbols you may see in a book (e.g. m-dash, various quoting characters, symbols for foot notes (and maybe Greek letters, etc.). Before and at start of Unicode we had standardized ISO/IEC 8859 (e.g. Latin-1), Microsoft Windows expanded (using reserved characters into the "Windows ANSI" encoding. But early Windows, and DOS had many other encodings.

Now, "code page" is a old term, when video memory was just a block of text. E.g. with early PC we had 80 columns x 25 rows of text. It was represented in memory by 80x25 bytes, and every bytes represented a character. A different table (maybe just in video card memory) had the pixel representation of the 256 characters. These are the "code page": the graphic representation of the characters. It is very similar to *encoding*, but it originated before encodings, and it was handled differently. In DOS you may change the codepage, but a program may not know about it, so it may *print* a character, but you may see a different one.

Note: code page included also box characters, for console interfaces, and maybe other symbols, and it may uses also "control characters". You cannot display a "new line", so you may use such code for other symbols (and a different way to print such symbols in a precise position). So this differentiate encoding (e.g. ASCII) with code page, but it is just an historical interest. Now we mostly use codepages as encoding, and always not considering the eventual symbols in control code part of ASCII. This just because we used the term `cp` (code point) on such times.

Answer (score -3):

A code page is a convention on how characters (and therefore strings) should be stored as data. ASCII, for instance, represents 128 characters in ... well, 128 numbers. You can take a look at a [table here](http://www.asciitable.com/) For instance, a capital G is the number 71, and the character `'0'` is 48.

ASCII was popular initially, but it only supported a very limited set of characters. A huge hassle occurred around the world because Koreans would a separate set of code pages to encode Korean, Russians used different code pages to support Cyrillic, ... so came Unicode, which supported most language characters, and nowadays even supports emojis. It's just another code page, but one with a large support system for most languages.

UTF-8 is a way of storing unicode in actual data. The 8 refers to 8 bits; that is, each character of UTF-8 can take up to 8 bits to store. UTF-16 is another way of storing unicode. It can take up to 16 bits to store data, and in some uses less space than UTF-8. However, nowadays, UTF-8 is by far the most popular encoding of unicode.